# jQuery UI Tabs, remove whitespace between tabs and tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI for my project and I can't seem to find the CSS to remove the 10 px or so white space between the actual tabs and the tab content.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a screen shot. What I am trying to remove is the whitespace between the tabs and the black bar which is within the content. Here is a screen shot http://imgur.com/a/Os8TQ

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css file/definition

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {    
    margin: 1px 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Would definitely avoid using `!important` as a rule, especially with jQuery UI, as it generates a lot of specificity that will make code maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried changing margin to padding but no luck. I dug pretty hard and tried a LOT of things before posting here. Doesn't work with or without important! applied. Thanks for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to target `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel` and remove the top padding; here's the default styling for this selector:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
display: block;
border-width: 0;
padding: 1em 1.4em;
background: none;
```

Here's a [fiddle demonstrating a basic tabs widget](https://jsfiddle.net/8wddaht0/) with an example black box like the one in your picture.

I'd strongly advise against using `!important` to override any styles, especially with regard to the jQuery UI widgets, as the script generates dynamic selectors with (in some cases) a high level of specificity.

I wrote [an article on Medium](https://medium.com/@webbcreativeio/jquery-ui-angled-tabs-tutorial-39ba174fb548) about how to style jQuery tabs; while not directly relevant to your existing problem, I do touch upon the specific dynamic classes for the widget. If you're looking for further help, it might aid you in some way.

Cheers!

Comment: I was already using padding: 0 0 0 0 !important; to get it to work as well as it is. If I remove !important, there is a huge margin. I also tried adding the same thing with margin instead of padding, no help. I should probably mention that the initial tab I create statically does not have this issue. The additional tabs I am creating dynamically have this issue. I have checked the content I am adding as to the dynamic tabs and there is no margin or padding issues that I can see. Somehow the space/gap is introduced as I create new tabs. Right now I just click a link that runs an addTab function

Comment: Tried to paste a code sample but, can't figure out how to do it in the reply box.

Comment: I feel like it's something about adding the tabs dynamically that's introducing the space. This http://imgur.com/IqNJGNx shows how there is no space in the default initial static tab.

Comment: So, I am a giant idiot, that's the problem.. I finally fixed it, many wasted hours digging through CSS just to figure out that it was a freakin' <p></p> tag set in this line `tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );`

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it, many wasted hours digging through CSS just to figure out that it was a freakin' `<p></p>` tag set in this line:
`tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );`

All other answers were fine and I didn't post enough of a code sample to give anyone else a chance at a solution. Was not sure who to award the answer to so I answered myself since this is what actually fixed the issue.

Thanks to the other folks who responded with info.